# How to pass data to related table in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

I have model:

```
class Product extends Model
{
   public function translate()
    {
        return $this->hasMany("App\ProductTranslate", "objectId", "id")->where('language', self::$language);
    }
}
```

When I add data to table `Product` I should add data to related table `ProductTranslate`.

I tried to do this as:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->title = "Name";
$product->translate()->name = "Value"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have the `hasMany` relation so when you call:

```
$product->translate()->get()
```

or

```
$product->translate
```

You'll get an *Eloquent* `Collection` of objects of type `App\ProductTranslate` so you itterate over them like so:

```
$product = new Product();
$product->title = "Name";
foreach ($product->translate as $translation) {
   $translation->name = "Value";
}
```

Comment: For what I must use `foreach` if there are notes in table?

Comment: As I said... you're using `hasMany` relation which always return a collection of models. If you made here a mistake - you can try with `belongsTo` relation. I don't know your  table structure.

Comment: Then I should to use: `$product = new Product(); $product->with("translate")?`

Answer (score 0):

Try this to insert a related model.

```
$product = new Product();
$product->title = "Name";
$product->save();

$product->translate()->create([
    'name' => 'Value'
]);
```

Also the documentation is very good at describing how to attach related models here.  https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models

Answer (score 0):

Store object in array and then pass array to view

```
$all_data = array()
for($i=0; $i< count($product); $i++)
{
  $product = new Product();
  $product->title = "Name";
  $product->translate()->name = "Value";

  $all_data[$i] = $product;
}
```

Pass data to view from controller

```
return view('admin.page')->with('all_data', $all_data)
```

UI part

```
<table id="table-data" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th width="5%" class="text-center">No.</th>
      <th>Name</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <?php $i = 1; ?>
    @foreach($all_data as $data)
      <tr>
        <td width="5%"><?php echo $i; ?></td>
        <td>{{ $data->name }}</td>       
      </tr> 
    <?php $i++; ?>
    @endforeach    
  </tbody>
</table>
```